# Can not get facebook sdk hash key.

Tags: android, facebook, alias, release, keystore

I want to get my release key hash for Facebook Android SDK.

I followed facebook getting started tutorial and it says paste this code to your terminal;

```
keytool -exportcert -alias YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS -keystore YOUR_RELEASE_KEY_PATH | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

When I paste this code to terminal with my key alias it says :

```
Illegal option:  sancaktaroglu
```

My key alias is **emre sancaktaroglu**, It contains space between my name and surname so I can not get my correct key hash. How can I solve this problem ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

From the [keytool documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/keytool.html):

> Option values must be quoted if they contain a blank (space).

So just quote it:

```
-alias "emre sancaktaroglu"
```

Answer (score 1):

$ keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" sha1 -binary |"C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl" base64

in case is needed
pass: android